# Sequence divs using javascript onclick

Tags: javascript, sorting, sequence

Is there a way to click on a div and save this click sequence value in the db.

Say I have ten items in 10 small small divs and I want them to be sorted in the sequence i click on them. So clicking on the first one will be sorted first and the next and then next.

Want to be able to do this with Javascript. Have seen this happening in desktop application where form fields are sequenced for tab order as you click on the fields.

Comment: there's a lot of binding and dom manipulation involved, which jQuery excels at. Are you opposed to using jQuery?

Comment: Thanks for the thought. I am not against useing jQuery. jQuery is also JavaScript is it not? I did not get specific about what exactly to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can give you a conceptual format, because a full-fledged deal will be quite long, and also because you've posted ***no code***.

- Ensure that each div has a unique id, and has at least one common CSS class e.g. `sortable` - this is critical, as it will allow you to query the DOM for those elements for further sorting. And, regarding ideas for the id of the divs, I have seen variations of usually some identifier like post id from a database;
- You have a listening function is run when the window is loaded, that listens for when any div that has the class `sortable` is clicked. You override the default action, and use the class in tandem with the div id to keep a record of which elements were clicked and sort them accordingly by whatever criteria you deem fit (id, date, content). However, then you have to manipulate the DOM to be modified to properly represent your new ordering. This can be done in two further ways:

  - Your sort can be real-time (which is laborious and involves higher RAM usage and a lot of DOM manipulation, but it is doable).
  - Or, option 2: perform a static sort where this information is passed via a form to another page, which redirects to the same page or a new page with the reordered DOM. Another way of doing that is to purge the DOM tree and rebuild it in the same page with Javascript using the sorted information upon the submission of a form, or the click of a button.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to bind to the click event of the divs, and pushing the div elements onto an array whenever they're clicked. Then you can use `.prepend()` to the container array by popping the elements from the array. Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/asifrc/897WJ/)..